# Body inteiro se movimentando

Tags: java, html, css, aplicação-web

O conteudo inteiro da minha pagina esta se movimentando, ao clicar e arrastar para os lados em qualquer lugar da tela, ja tentei varias soluções mas nenhuma esta impedindo este comportamento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Strix</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-NhSC1YmyruXifcj/KFRWoC561YpHpc5Jtzgvbuzx5VozKpWvQ+4nXhPdFgmx8xqexRcpAglTj9sIBWINXa8x5w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&family=PT+Serif:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,500;0,700;1,300&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda:wght@400;600;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/global.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slider-header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slider-popular-movie.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slider-upcoming.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p class="title-site">Strix</p>
    <section class="slider">
        <p class="title-slider-now-playing">Filmes agora no cinema</p>

        <div class="slider-content" id="content">
            <input type="radio" name="btn-radio" id="radio1">
            <input type="radio" name="btn-radio" id="radio2">
            <input type="radio" name="btn-radio" id="radio3">

            <div class="slide-box first"></div>
            <div class="slide-box"></div>
            <div class="slide-box"></div>

            <div class="nav-auto">
                <div class="auto-btn1"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-manual">
                <label id="manual-btn1" for="radio1" class="manual-btn"></label>
                <label id="manual-btn2" for="radio2" class="manual-btn"></label>
                <label id="manual-btn3" for="radio3" class="manual-btn"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="slider-popular-movie">
        <p class="title-slider-popular">Filmes populares</p>

        <div class="slider-popular-movie-content" id="content-popular-movie">

            <div class="content-imgs-popular-movie">
                <span class="slide-box-popular-movie first"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-popular-movie"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-popular-movie"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-popular-movie"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-popular-movie"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-auto-popular-movie">
                <div class="auto-btn1-popular-movie"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2-popular-movie"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3-popular-movie"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class="slider-upcoming">
        <p class="title-slider-upcoming">Estão por vir</p>

        <div class="slider-upcoming-content" id="content-upcoming">

            <div class="content-imgs-upcoming">
                <span class="slide-box-upcoming first"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-upcoming"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-upcoming"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-upcoming"></span>
                <span class="slide-box-upcoming"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="nav-auto-upcoming">
                <div class="auto-btn1-upcoming"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn2-upcoming"></div>
                <div class="auto-btn3-upcoming"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <script src="assets/js/api.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/popularMovie.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/upcoming.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
*{
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
}
```

```
section .slider-popular-movie {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
 }

.title-slider-popular {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin: 0.25rem 1rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.slider-popular-movie-content {
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 35vh;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider-popular-movie-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

.slide-box-popular-movie img {
    width: 45vw;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 599px) and (max-width: 879px){
    section .slider-popular-movie {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
     }
     .slider-popular-movie-content {
        max-width: 100vw;
        height: 40vh;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    .slider-popular-movie-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
        display: none;
    }
    
    .slide-box-popular-movie img {
        width: 35vw;
        height: 90%;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 880px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
    section .slider-popular-movie {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
     }
     .slider-popular-movie-content {
        max-width: 100vw;
        height: 70vh;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    .slider-popular-movie-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
        display: none;
    }
    
    .slide-box-popular-movie img {
        width: 30vw;
        height: 90%;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    section .slider-popular-movie {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
     }
     .slider-popular-movie-content {
        max-width: 100vw;
        height: 70vh;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    .slider-popular-movie-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
        display: none;
    }
    
    .slide-box-popular-movie img {
        width: 20vw;
        height: 90%;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

```
.title-site{
    display: flex;
    margin: 1rem 0 auto;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

section.slider {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.slider-content {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title-slider-now-playing{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin: 0.25rem 1rem;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.slider-content input {
    display: none;
}

.slide-box {
    width: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
}

.slide-box img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 95%;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-manual, .nav-auto {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 }

.nav-manual .manual-btn,
.nav-auto div {
    border: 1px solid #205ca1;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}

.nav-manual .manual-btn:not(:last-child),
.nav-auto div:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-manual .manual-btn.active {
    background-color: black;
}

input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
    background-color: white;
}

#radio1:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn1,
#radio2:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn2,
#radio3:checked~.nav-auto .auto-btn3 {
    background-color: black;
}

#radio1:not(:checked)~.nav-auto .auto-btn1,
#radio2:not(:checked)~.nav-auto .auto-btn2,
#radio3:not(:checked)~.nav-auto .auto-btn3 {
    background-color: white;
}

#radio1:checked~.first {
    margin-left: 0%;
}

#radio2:checked~.first {
    margin-left: -100%;
}

#radio3:checked~.first {
    margin-left: -200%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 599px) and (max-width: 879px){
    section.slider {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 40vh;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .slider-content {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slide-box {
        width: 100%;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    
    .slide-box img {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 95%;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        padding: 0.5rem;
    }

    .nav-manual, .nav-auto {
        position: absolute;
        top: 85%;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
     }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 880px) and (max-width: 1279px){
    section.slider {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 70vh;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .slider-content {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slide-box {
        width: 100%;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    
    .slide-box img {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 95%;
        border-radius: 3rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        padding-right: 2rem;
    }

    .nav-manual, .nav-auto {
        position: absolute;
        top: 85%;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
     }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px){
    section.slider {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 95vh;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .slider-content {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 90%;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slide-box {
        width: 100%;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    
    .slide-box img {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 95%;
        border-radius: 3rem;
        padding-left: 2rem;
        padding-right: 2rem;
    }

    .nav-manual, .nav-auto {
        position: absolute;
        top: 85%;
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
     }
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

como eu não tenho o projeto inteiro, para mim, oq está causando o problema é  esse css aqui

```
    .nav-manual,
    .nav-auto {
     position: absolute;
     top: 85%;
     width: 100vw;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
  }
```

como ele possui position absolute e um width de 100vw, ele ultrapassa os limites do body. Resolva o problema trocando o width de 100vw para 100%.

```
    .nav-manual,
    .nav-auto {
     position: absolute;
     top: 85%;
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
  }
```

faça isso em todos os @media screen tbm

Comment: continuou com o mesmo comportamento, ao manter pressionado e arrastar, todos os elementos da pag se movem em conjunto

Comment: consegue me mandar o html?

Comment: vou editar a pergunta e colocar o HTML

Comment: editei a resposta com oq eu acredito ser a solução, espero que tenha ajudado

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!!!